# JQuery Do something if specific text find in label control

Tags: jquery

I need to do something if "Door Entry" or "Phone Call" text is found within the label control, as shown in given below HTML code:

```js
if ($("("label[for=risk_form_purpose_of_one]"):contains('Door Entry')")) {
  document.getElementById("add-function").value = "Add Priority Function";
  getDropDownDiv.style.display = "block";
  getDropDownContentDiv.style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("fieldsetSize").style.height = "1000px";
  dropDownChanged = true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="acdo01" for="risk_form_purpose_of_one">
      <span style="width:1px;"></span>
      <span class="acdo_disabled" style="width:140px;">Door Entry</span>
    </label>
```

Comment: Get the element by className and use it's innerHTML to check for the flag.

Comment: we have to find element by for="risk_form_purpose_of_one" value as there will be many labels with same class name

Comment: "*I need to do something..*" such as? Please be explicit in your questions as to what you wish to achieve, reading (presumably broken, non-working) code to infer your intent isn't going be particularly accurate most of the time, in most occasions.

Comment: hi David as shown in JQuery code which I am trying to achieve that I have to hide few controls if label control contain "Door Entry" or "Phone Call"

Comment: Sure, but as shown in your code you're also trying to find an element with an `id="add-function"`, which doesn't exist in your HTML, which is why I asked you to be explicit (incidentally, if that element is important add it to your HTML, if it's not important or relevant, then remove it from your code). There's the same issue with the `#fieldsetSize` element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector?retiredLocale=nl) with the following css selector

```css
label.acdo01[for = "risk_form_purpose_of_one"] > span.acdo_disabled
```

Which means:

- `<label>` with class `.acdo01` and `for` `risk_form_purpose_of_one`
- Take the child `<span`> with class `acdo_disabled`

Then you can use `innerHTML` to toggle the flag:

```js
const e = document.querySelector('label.acdo01[for = "risk_form_purpose_of_one"] > span.acdo_disabled');

if (e && e.innerHTML === 'Door Entry') {
  console.log('Do something');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="acdo01" for="risk_form_purpose_of_one">
  <span style="width:1px;"></span>
  <span class="acdo_disabled" style="width:140px;">Door Entry</span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the label[for='risk_form_purpose_of_one'] containing or 'Door Entry' or 'Phone Call' with the following line:

```
$("label[for='risk_form_purpose_of_one']").filter(":contains('Door Entry'), :contains('Phone Call')");
```

Then you can loop through the results to take action on those single elements isolated.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you!!

```js
if ($("label[for='risk_form_purpose_of_one'] span:contains('Door Entry')").length > 0 || $("label[for='risk_form_purpose_of_one'] span:contains('Phone Call')").length > 0) {
  console.log('do your code');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="acdo01" for="risk_form_purpose_of_one">
    <span style="width:1px;"></span>
    <span class="acdo_disabled" style="width:140px;">Door Entry</span>
</label>
```